# How to save multiple categories in magento 2

Tags: magento2, category, magento-2.0, category-tree

How to save multiple categories. For a single category using the method save.

Ejm.: Save category1, category2, category3, ... category100. How to save 100 in 100 categories.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by deleting the spaces.

category1,category2,category3, ...